# Android Thread Stackoverflow

Tags: android, multithreading, stack-overflow

Hy
I am developing a programm with some thread and sometime I get this error message:

```
11-03 18:58:06.047: I/dalvikvm(3587): threadid=15: stack overflow on call to      Ljava/lang/ref/FinalizerReference;.<init>:VLL
11-03 18:58:06.047: I/dalvikvm(3587):   method requires 12+20+12=44 bytes, fp is 0x591ad314 (20 left)
11-03 18:58:06.047: I/dalvikvm(3587):   expanding stack end (0x591ad300 to 0x591ad000)
11-03 18:58:06.047: I/dalvikvm(3587): Shrank stack (to 0x591ad300, curFrame is 0x591ad328)
```

I use this code for outputing all my active threads:

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);   
for(int i=0;i<threadArray.length;i++){
    Log.e("Threadtest", threadArray[i].getName()+"|"+ threadArray[i].getClass()+"|"+ threadArray[i].getId());
}
```

This is the output:

```
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): Signal Catcher|class java.lang.Thread|205
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): Compiler|class java.lang.Thread|207
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): FinalizerWatchdogDaemon|class java.lang.Thread|210
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): pool-1-thread-1|class java.lang.Thread|217
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): Binder_1|class java.lang.Thread|211
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): ReferenceQueueDaemon|class java.lang.Thread|208
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): Thread-224|class java.lang.Thread|224
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): JDWP|class java.lang.Thread|206
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): main|class java.lang.Thread|1
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): Thread-214|class com.example.evosoft.ComUSB.Send.GCodeSender|214
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): Thread-213|class com.example.evosoft.PrinterInfoSender|213
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): Thread-215|class com.example.evosoft.ComUSB.UsbConnectionChecker|215
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): GC|class java.lang.Thread|204
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): Binder_2|class java.lang.Thread|212
11-03 18:58:02.847: E/Threadtest(3587): FinalizerDaemon|class java.lang.Thread|209
```

It would help me a lot when i know in which thread the error happens.

best regards
markus

Comment: I would recommomend you to use threadpools instead of Sets of threads: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: more code will be helpful. Also, since the error is stack overflow you should check all the places that you're calling a method recursively.

Comment: i think i have called nothing recursively.
i need to know in which thread it happens to post more code or finde the error :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the basics about [Threads in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) like **never** interact with the GUI from outside of the UI Thread?

Comment: thanks for your reply
i call an permission for usb from a not gui thread. isnt this ok?